# i want to update hashmap in firebase firestore by the use of functions node js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I try to update the object as a hash map in Firestore but that object is considered as a string. And the address is updated as the string in Firestore.

```
exports.updateStoreDetails = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
        if(req.method === "POST") {

            const address = req.body.address;
            const pincode = req.body.pincode;
            const landmark = req.body.landmark;
            const latitude = req.body.latitude;
            const longitude = req.body.longitude;


            var object = {
                "address" : address,
                "pincode" : pincode,
                "landmark": landmark,
                "latitude": latitude,
                "longitude": longitude
            }

            var db = admin.firestore();
            let Ref = db.collection('RetailerStores').doc(retailerUid);
            let updateSingle = Ref.update({
                address : object
                });
            updateSingle.then(function(){
                res.status(200).send("updated");
                return null;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error" + error);
            })  

        }else {
            res.status(500).send("Not Allowed!")
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects):

> If your document contains nested objects, you can use "dot notation" to reference nested fields within the document when you call **update**().

So, you can do this to solve your problem:

```
const object = {
    "address.address": address,
    "address.pincode": pincode,
    "address.landmark": landmark,
    "address.latitude": latitude,
    "address.longitude": longitude
}

const db = admin.firestore();
const ref = db.doc(`RetailerStores/${retailerUid}`);
const updateSingle = ref.update({ address: object });
```